# Reference qualifier not working as expected in Variable in Catalog Item in Service Now

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Service Now. I'm working on a catalog item. There i have a variable called listId which is a Reference Type. In Type Specification I'm referencing it to a table service_offer and in Reference qualifier I have written this:

```
javascript: new
OfferingServices().gettingList(current.variables.account);
```

I am getting all values in the table while I'm expecting it to give me values based on account.
Note: The script include is client callable.
Here is my script include code for OfferingServices()

```
var OfferingServices = Class.create();
OfferingServices.prototype = Object.extendsObject(global.AbstractAjaxProcessor, {
    
var OfferingServices = Class.create();
OfferingServices.prototype = Object.extendsObject(global.AbstractAjaxProcessor, {
    gettingList: function(value){
        var results = [];
        if(value){
                var gr = new GlideRecord('service_offer');
                gr.addQuery('account.sys_id', value);
                gr.query();
                while (gr.next()) {
                    results.push({
                        name: gr.getValue('name'),
                        deviceSolutionID: gr.getValue('sol_id')
                    });
                }
            }
            gs.info('JSON.stringify(results) ==> '+JSON.stringify(results));
            return JSON.stringify(results);
        }
    });
});
```

When i run this, in logger table i get JSON.stringify(results) ==> [] but in that field, i am getting all the values in service_offer table.

Answer (score 0):

Aafter reading more about it, I finally be able to solve it by adding this to my query

```
javascript: "sys_idIN" + new
OfferingServices().gettingList(current.variables.account)
```